# Bitmapdata.draw(MovieClip) Gives Blank BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, bitmapdata, adobe-illustrator

I'm predrawing all vector element in my game to bitmaps to improve performance - the vector elements are exported as swf files from Illustrator (I suspect that is part of the problem).
When embedding the swf file in as3 like so:

```
[Embed(source = 'file.swf')] private static const image:Class;
```

And then adding it to the stage, like so

```
stage.addChild(new image);
```

Everything is fine, but if instead I draw it to a bitmap data like so...

```
genericBitmapData.draw(new image);
```

It's a blank bitmapdata. I've tried using `gotoAndStop` on frames 0 and 1 before drawing with no avail. Does anyone have experience with the swf files that Illustrator exports and any insight as to how I can get these drawing as expected?

[Here](http://abscure.net/files/button-01.swf) is a link to a really simple .swf that produces the same results

Comment: Hi. Can you publish somewhere example of such swf file?

Comment: @kostik I added a link to the end of the question.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the genericBitmapData ?

Comment: @prototypical It varies depending on context, though now I'm making it so it's the width of the movieclip for testing purposes (taking scaling into account as well)

Comment: I think I find reason. Try this code: http://pastebin.com/YgamqtKU Loader instance never fire any event. And from Event.ENTER_FRAME handler for me it trace: [object AVM1Movie]. And AVM2 swf will not able to draw AVM1Movie. Try change export parameters in Illustrator

Comment: >Loader instance never fire any event - it's too late for me. I'm add handlers for not for contentLoaderInfo :) This is correct code: http://pastebin.com/BP4kyMBm and Loader instance fire events but button-01.swf is AVM1Movie

Comment: I think I know what this is. There's a weird thing, where even though the asset is embedded, it still loads like if you to use the Loader class. I can't remember exactly right now though, will take a look at my code later tonight.

Comment: The follow up being that when you add as a child, it replaces it once loaded - but when you draw to bitmap, it takes what's there at that instant, and doesn't update once its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my revised solution:

```
//create movieclip
var mc:MovieClip = new image();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

//this gets called on next frame
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    genericBitmapData.draw(mc);
}
```

Comment: I don't add it to the stage - I just did it for testing purposes. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Ah, i see. It could be that the swf doesnt have time to instantiate itself before it is 'copied'. Try adding it to stage (can set visible=false) and then calling draw. You may also need to wait for next frame before there's anything to copy.

Comment: Or this may work: genericBitmapData.draw(new image() as MovieClip);

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, I think you're right in that maybe the object hasn't had time to instantiate, but neither of those work. Will the object always instantiate on the next frame or can it take any amount of time?

Comment: Just tested this with an instance of the image class created in line, and the bitmapdata.draw(imageInstance) called after an ENTER_FRAME event, and it took two frames for the swf to draw. I assume the first ENTER_FRAME is still the instantiating frame.

Comment: I guess it could take 2 frames to prepare - i havent used timeline for soooo long i forget its 'features'. I assume that first frame of loaded swf does actually have content to see?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the object needs to be instantiated before I can use it to draw, and the easiest way to detect when that is is to listen for the `ENTER_FRAME` event:

```
(new image).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, functionToDrawImage);
```

And when that function is called, it will be ready to draw to a bitmapdata, and then all is right with the world.

Comment: You should remove the event listener afer draw is complete otherwise it will keep calling functionToDrawImage on every frame. See my revised answer